# Network Install Debian on a VLAN

Tags: debian, dependencies, vlan

My lab is on a VLAN. If the machines are connected to the VLAN they can connect to the Internet. If not they can't. Installing the VLAN package enables network connectivity. However, I don't know how load a .deb during an install. I tried installing a base system without network connectivity -- however, that failed when trying to install anything beyond VLAN. Namely, it was caught in a dependencies loop for libc6, libgcc1, and libstd++6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a VLAN package on Debian unless you are configuring the Debian box as a VLAN switch. As long as the Debian machine has a NIC in that VLAN that is routed to the Internet.

If machines are connected and during installation you configure the IP address and DNS server, are you able to scan the mirror during installation?